# Fragment cannot be resolved to a type after adding support library in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I want to use Fragment  and action bar in my project for android 2.2 so I had added Support Library- v4 and v7 in but still I am getting error as

> Fragment cannot be resolved to a type and The method getActionBar() is undefined for the type MainActivity.

here is my code:

```
import java.util.Locale;

import android.R;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.appcompat.*;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionbar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
    R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionbar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionbar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content
    // view
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
     // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_websearch:
        // create intent to perform web search for this planet
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getSupportActionbar()().getTitle());
        // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getSupportActionbar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
 */
public static class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet,
                container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources()
                .getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(
                planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()), "drawable",
                getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image))
                .setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Now here I had tried both

`getSupportActionbar()` and and `getActionBar()`. But both gives error.

Also I have `activity_main.xml` file but in `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` also it gives error as `activity_main` cannot be resolved or is not a field`

I had already setup compact library file in below screen shot

[image]

Comment: use `getSupportActionbar()`

Comment: @Raghunandan now getting arror as The method getSupportActionbar() is undefined for the type MainActivity. and Fragment error is also there

Comment: your `activity` class should extend `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: instead of screen shot it would be better you post the code here

Comment: do you have activity_main.xml under res/layout  and check if you have any errors in your resource files

Comment: also remove `import android.R`

Comment: @Raghunandan I have activity_main.xml under res/layout. Now I am getting error R cannot be resolved to a variable. And getSupportActionbar() error is still there. yes I had removed import android.R

Comment: if you have errors in your resource files your `R.java` under gen folder will not be generated. Seems you have errors in your resource files. Make sure you fix them first

Comment: @Raghunandan it is not showing any error in xml file. But still showing error as - R cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39409/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-ppd)

Comment: clean and build see if you have any errors in any of resources files. Check if you have `R.java` under gen folder. And use chat section above comment link foo further comenting

Comment: It shows me multiple errors like-D:\AndroidWorkSpace\MutualFund\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v14\styles_base.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.

Comment: then set up your app compact library properly first.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If supporting API levels **lower than 11**: 
`import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`

Also your fragment import must be from support library `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()`. Your activity must extend `ActionBarActivity`.

In Fragment

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Title");
```

Check the topic adding the action bar

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Edit:

CHange

```
 getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

to

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Remove

```
 import android.R;
```

Comment: I get a cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity when I run ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Title");

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use `getSupportActionBar()` instead of `getActionBar()` if you're using the support library.
2. Make sure your `Fragment` is from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` namespace - this one is from the support library.